# Python re.sub() is not substituting a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, substitution

Hey Guys Need Your Help Here.

This is my sample code

```
import random
import string
import re
str=r'im a boy \\x%02X'
result = re.sub('\\\\x%02X', re.escape('\x5c\x5c\x78\x25\x30\x32\x58'), str, 0)
print(" Code=\n", result)
```

So when i took output from this program. The output is:
Code=
im a boy \\x%02X

But it is supposed to be like this/

Code=
im a boy \x5c\x5c\x78\x25\x30\x32\x58

Why it is not replacing??

Comment: Why did you tell `re.sub` to replace 0 times with the last `0`? Remove it.

Comment: Because if the str has multiple repetition \\x%02X' of it then it will replace all the occurrences.

Comment: So, you want to replace the first occurrence? Pass `1`, not `0`.

Comment: But other than that why it is not substituting the value.?

Comment: I want to replace all the occurrences on the code. As this is just a 1% code of my actual program that's why the syntax is like this.

Comment: `'\x5c\x5c\x78\x25\x30\x32\x58'` is one way of writing the string `\\x%02X`; it uses hexadecimal escape sequences, for no apparent reason.  So you're basically replacing that substring with itself.  If you want the replacement to be that literal string, with seven backslashes and x's in it, put a `r` in front to make it a raw string literal.

Comment: Ok, `re.escape('\x5c\x5c\x78\x25\x30\x32\x58')` is `\\\\x%02X` text, exactly the pattern you are trying to write, but you wrote ``\\x%02X``. `'\\\\x%02X'` = `\\x%02X` text.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper. i forgot to put r in front of the string. It really helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a number of mistakes in your code, which makes me wonder if `r'im a boy \\x%02X'` is actually a correct representation of your input.

Assuming it is:

```
import re

s = r'im a boy \\x%02X'
result = re.sub(r'\\\\x%02X', re.escape(r'\x5c\x5c\x78\x25\x30\x32\x58'), s)
print(result)
```

Some of the problems with your code:

- Why is `random` in there? And `string`?
- Don't name variables so that they shadow basic types (or any builtins), `str` is a bad name
- Without the `r` the `\x5c[etc]` string will turn into the exact same string as you had before, defined as bytes.
- Why use the byte representation of the exact same text as a the replacement for the text?
- Why tell `re.sub` to only replace `0` times?

By the way, from what you appear to be trying here, I wonder if you realise that what you're printing and what the actual value of a variable is, isn't exactly the same thing. What you print is the text representation of the value, not the actual value.

You would do well to explain why you're attempting this replacement, as this may be a typical XY problem.

Comment: Your queries are correct but its just a sample code made by me to clarify what is the mistake on my real code. In a hurry i just use str variable name. And i need the exact same string in a Unicode representation that's why using that. And at last 0 times means multiple occurrences so that's why i used it in my code to find multiple occurrences.